# Generating directories/sub-directories and files

Tags: python, file-io

Hi I am currently a beginner to the python language, it is also my first language too. I need some help I am finding it difficult to know what to use to generate permanent directories sub directories and files, for eg; I want the path to generate whatever path i enter if the directories etc. don't exist, i want them created, so I enter C:\user\python\directory\sub-directory\file, then i cant workout what i should import to do the following job.

I am using Python 3.2, any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import os
os.makedirs('a/b/c', exist_ok=True)
```

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("c:\file\path","w")
f.write("content of file")
```

First, you open the file, storing it in variable `f`.

You then write to it, using `f.write()`

Python will create the file and path if it does not exist, I think. (I am sure I've done this before, but I can't remember)

When you have finished using the file, you should use

```
f.close()
```

to close the file safely.

Comment: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I think it will only create the file, not the whole directory tree. (I'm on Py2.7 Linux, but I don't think it makes a difference)

Comment: Just tested that and yeah, I think you may be write.